# JSF logout using session.invalidate does not clear the current session

Tags: jsp, logout, httpsession

I am trying to use FacesContext `invalidateSession` method to clear the session when logout. However when I try to log in again, I got the error

*Component ID form-dynamicTableBean0:devicesTable-dynamicTableBean0:j_idt1454:DNP_ANALOGS has already been found in the view.*

It seems the session is not cleared out yet. 
This is my logout code:

```
public void logout() {
    // ((HttpSession)
    // FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true)).invalidate();

    // redirect to your login view:
    try {
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
          .getRequest();
      request.logout();
      ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

      ec.invalidateSession();
      weblogic.servlet.security.ServletAuthentication.invalidateAll(request);
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/login.html");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Log out failed:", e);
    }
  }
```

If I comment out these two lines...

```
ec.invalidateSession();
weblogic.servlet.security.ServletAuthentication.invalidateAll(request);
```

I don't get the error, however, the session does not clear and I can still see stuff from the previous session.

How do I correctly to clear the session, or do you think that the error is related to the logout?